# Any mature solutions to create a instant shell with ELF symbols and c grammar command parser?

Tags: c, shell, yacc, lex, elf

I need to make a debug shell inside each c exe(linux enviroment), and my solution is as follows:

1. Read elf symbols from exe file, build a symbol->address table in
   memory;
2. Run a thread calling readline to accept user input, some thing
   like a c function call;
3. use Lex & yacc to parse the function name and arg list;
4. Find address of the function in the symbol table;
5. Call the function with args list;
6. Every function written can be input as shell command instantly.

I don't think this is a fresh idea, and my question is: Are there any mature codes implemented already? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I program in linux, Windows will be never considered

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing, but it *is* an intriguing idea. You may have to explore it on your own. [Or post some code!]

Comment: to knizz： the project will be deployed without gdb, so something similiar as gdb's "call" command can make it easy-to-use.

Comment: why not take what you need from gdb, make it a library that you link into your projects? (I think that is legal, but not sure). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter since gdb is GPL software, it is legal if the program itself is also distributed under GPL.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. If you had working with VxWorks, you'll find WindShell is what you're looking for. I had port a similar shell to Linux. You can download the source from:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/zprj/

Note: don't use the source in commercial products, since they are ported from WindShell. If you do want a shell in commercial fields, then you shall develop one with LEX/YACC.

Comment: Hey, I have developed a new cshell, even more features talked here, with lex and bison. Anyone could comment his email here, so I can send the source to you. It's 100% open, free.